# Android - How to center Path on Canvas to screen with a given X and Y coordinate as the center

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I have the following code to draw a path to a Canvas:

```
if (mPointArray.size() > 1) {
    mPath.moveTo(mPointArray.get(0).x * scaleX, mPointArray.get(0).y * scaleY);
    for (int x = 1; x < mPointArray.size(); x++) {
        mPath.lineTo(mPointArray.get(x).x * scaleX, mPointArray.get(x).y * scaleY);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);    
    canvas.drawPoint(mPointArray.get(mPointArray.size() - 1).x * scaleX, mPointArray.get(mPointArray.size() - 1).y * scaleY, pointPaint);
}
```

Say I were to have an arbitrary X and Y coordinate as a designated center, how would I apply that X and Y coordinate to the center of the screen?  The reason why I am asking is because I am developing an app where you stand on a sensor where you stand on a specific location, and I would like my path to be centered around that initial point before drawing the path.  I have two float values, `centerX` and `centerY` that I would somehow like to apply to my path. Unfortunately, if I apply them before multiplying by `scaleX` and `scaleY`, the translation is too large, while if I do it afterwards, the translation is too small.

Here is the declaration for `scaleX`:

`scaleX = ((screenW / sensorWidth) * 1.1f) - ((screenW / sensorWidth) * 0.1f);`

`scaleY` is definied similarly in terms of `screenH` and `sensorLength`.

How would I apply the new center coordinates of the sensor, with the new center being centered on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got your question, but this formula looks sick:

scaleX = ((screenW / sensorWidth) * 1.1f) - ((screenW / sensorWidth) * 0.1f);

A  simpler version of this would be:

scaleX = screenW / sensorWidth;

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it:
`mPath.offset((centerX - (sensorWidth / 2)) * -scaleX, (centerY - (sensorLength / 2)) * -scaleY);`